# Executing multiple commands from a Windows cmd script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, cmd

I'm trying to write a Windows cmd script to perform several tasks in series.
However, it always stops after the first command in the script.

The command it stops after is a maven build (not sure if that's relevant).

How do I make it carry on and run each task in turn please?

Installing any software or configuring the registry etc is completely out of the question - it has to work on a vanilla Windows XP installation I'm afraid.

Ideally I'd like the script to abort if any of the commands failed, but that's a "nice to have", not essential.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you trying to start a bat file. Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/64720570/388389

Answer (score 144, accepted):

When you call another .bat file, I think you need "call" in front of the call:

```
call otherCommand.bat
```

Comment: Hi, in the original script I wasn't calling other .cmd files, but I have since split it into separate files so I could run each in turn.
So, putting call in front of each command seems to have done the trick, thanks!

Comment: As a matter of fact, on Windows, `mvn` is a .bat file by itself, thus you need to use `call` for it as in `call mvn install`; normally you don't need to create an extra cmd file.

Comment: Note that you don't need semicolons in batch files. And the reason why you need to use call is that mvn itself is a batch file and batch files need to call each other with call, otherwise control does not return to the caller.

Comment: @Gulzar Nazim - Do you know if I can put all the commands in a single batch file with if-else statement as I don't want to maintain it in different batch files?

Comment: The irony here is the answer is pointing in the opposite direction of the question and still it gets 120 upvotes

Comment: I was trying to do something similar with `npm` updates and `protractor` tests. I didn't think this answer applied to me until I realized `npm` and `protractor` are `.cmd` files on Windows.

Answer (score 45):

You can use the && symbol between commands to execute the second command only if the first succeeds.  More info here http://commandwindows.com/command1.htm

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try in conjunction with the accepted answer above.

Comment: Will this stop the execution of the second script if maven build fails?

Comment: That link is broken: "Backend server did not respond in time.
App server is too busy and cannot handle requests in time."

Comment: Can someone explain to me why `calc && echo foo` results in the calculator being started and "foo" being printed immediately? How can I start `calc` in a way that it blocks the windows shell like the bash does without `&`?

Comment: @TheM Windows distinguishes between GUI-based and command-based applications (there is a flag in near the beginning of the EXE file). If you start a GUI-based application from the command line it always appears to end immediately since it is completely detached from the command-line. If you start a command-based program from a GUI program (like Explorer) it will always show a new command line. POSIX systems make no such distinction thus the behavior is more consistent.

Comment: @TheM To get around this you can use `start /B /WAIT calc`

Comment: @coderforlife I agree that this behavior is somewhat inconsistent but at least there is a way to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

Not sure why the first command is stopping.
If you can make it parallel, you can try something like

```
start cmd.exe /C 1.bat      
start cmd.exe /C 2.bat
```

Comment: Use `/K` instead of `/C` if you want the shell to remain open after your command has executed.

Comment: No need to use `cmd.exe` and `start`, just `start x.bat1` will do.

Answer (score 23):

I have just been doing the exact same(ish) task of creating a batch script to run maven test scripts. The problem is that calling maven scrips with mvn clean install ... is itself a script and so needs to be done with call mvn clean install.

Code that will work

```
rem run a maven clean install
cd C:\rbe-ui-test-suite 
call mvn clean install
rem now run through all the test scripts
call mvn clean install -Prun-integration-tests -Dpattern=tc-login
call mvn clean install -Prun-integration-tests -Dpattern=login-1
```

Note rather the use of call. This will allow the use of consecutive maven scripts in the batch file.

Answer (score 6):

Using double ampersands will run the second command, only if the first one succeeds:

```
cd Desktop/project-directory && atom .
```

Where as, using only one ampersand will attempt to run both commands, even if the first fails:

```
cd Desktop/project-directory & atom .
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the direct answer to your question, but if you do a lot of these scripts, it might be worth learning a more powerful language like perl.  Free implementations exist for Windows (e.g. activestate, cygwin).  I've found it worth the initial effort for my own tasks.

**Edit:**

As suggested by @Ferruccio, if you can't install extra software, consider vbscript and/or javascript.  They're built into the Windows scripting host.

Comment: Thanks but I am unable to install any software.
I wish I had access to something more powerful than the crappy Windows scripting language. :-(

Comment: You can always use vbscript or javascript. They're built into the Windows scripting host.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in Windows you can use the following command.

Drive:

```
cd "Script location"
schtasks /run /tn "TASK1"
schtasks /run /tn "TASK2"
schtasks /run /tn "TASK3"
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't need semicolons in batch files. And the reason why you need to use call is that mvn itself is a batch file and batch files need to call each other with call, otherwise control does not return to the caller.