# how to run multiple batch files in serial, in windows command line environment

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file,

```
bat1.bat
bat2.bat
```

but it stops at the end of bat1

any clues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run multiple bat files within a bat file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `call`:

```
call bat1.cmd
call bat2.cmd
```

By default, when you just run a batch file from another one controll will not pass back to the calling one. That's why you need to use `call`.

Basically, if you have a batch like this:

```
@echo off
echo Foo
batch2.cmd
echo Bar
```

then it will only output

```
Foo
```

If you write it like

```
@echo off
echo Foo
call batch2.cmd
echo Bar
```

however, it will output

```
Foo
Bar
```

because after `batch2` terminates, program control is passed back to your original batch file.

Comment: second example identical to first, but I got the point. Works perfectly

Comment: I think the second example is missing a "call."

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if bat1.bat stops abnormally (other than just running to the end, like calling exit) and you can work around this by using a fresh cmd.exe to run each bat file:

```
start /b /wait bat1.bat
start /b /wait bat2.bat
```

You could omit it for the last one if there won't follow commands in you bat file.

Comment: No, it also happens if the batch terminates normally. Using `start` here is overkill, though. And you need an extra `exit` at the end of the sub-batches to kill the `cmd` process that is spawned. Otherwise you find yourself on a new console after the first batch ran.

Answer (score 1):

Something else to look for:

I had a similar issue where I was calling multiple batch files using the `call` command but it did not pass back the control to the original .bat file.

I found out that I had an `exit` command at the end of the batch file which closed the DOS window before going back to the original `.bat` file and finishing the commands there.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run the multiple .exe files in one go, firstly you need to create .bat file and then add all of your .exe files as below:

```
  D:\Data\Feed.exe Books.xml
  D:\Data\Feed.exe Mobile.xml
  D:\Data\Feed.exe Clothes.xml
```

And then save as something.bat then give it a run with cmd.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run batchfiles in sequence you will have to put "start bat1.bat" at the end of each file.