# How to start two servers (mysqld and thin) in one batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file to start MySQL server (`mysqld`) and Rails Thin server (`rails s thin`). But only MySQL starts, `rails s thin` doesn't:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\path\to\app
CMD /C "mysqld --console"
REM exit  <-- with or without it
REM cd C:\path\to\app  <-- with or without it
CMD /C "rails s thin"
```

I also tried to create three files for this. The main one runs other two. Doesn't help either, only MySQL runs. And I need to start MySQL before Rails. Rails needs running MySQL. How to write such a batch?

**UPD:**
[How to start 2 programs simultaniously in windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487766/how-to-start-2-programs-simultaniously-in-windows-command-prompt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use start

e.g.

start notepad.exe

start calc.exe

if you want to run one after another with some tests, you may need to write your own program.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm trying it out now and it is working :) Now experimenting with options that may be passed to `start` command. Thank you.