# .exe runs subsequently fails only when run from command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, bin

I have a cmd line to run an executable called 'Invertor':

```
Invertor  /g /d /i
```

Program 'Invertor' starts but then fails when it can't later when it can't open a corresponding .bin file.  The .bin file IS in the same directory as .exe so at least should be found.  The Invertor program is fine when I open it by double clicking the icon, so the program is working.

Do I have a problem with the /g /d /i options? Am I missing one?

Thanks

Comment: did you try any other commands? like creating an instance of the program?

Comment: No, good idea, how would I do that?

Comment: No idea. But it is possible. Let me look it up reel quik.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487766/how-to-start-2-programs-simultaniously-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: When you run the program by double-clicking the executable, there won't be any command-line arguments.  What do the `/g` `/d` and `/i` flags actually do?  Why are you specifying them?

Comment: Also, when you run the program by double-clicking the executable, the current directory will be the directory the executable is in.  That might not be true in a batch file if the program is on the PATH or if you specify the full path to the executable.

Comment: Harry- Specifying the full path worked (thanks) but the path was specified in computer environment anyway (thats why it would work initially).  I don't fully understand why the path needs specifying again? My undertsanding of the flags was so that paths to various files would be considered... obviously I was wrong.

Comment: EgMusic- Im taking a look at that now :)

Comment: Uh ... actually, I thought that specifying the full path might be *causing* the problem, not that it might fix it.  But whatever I guess.  If in doubt about the flags, you need to look at the documentation for "Invertor", or ask for help from the developer - they're the only people who would know.  You can check whether the executable can be found on the path by running `where invertor` in a command shell.

Comment: This isn't really even a code question.  You are asking us how to use a specific piece of software.  That is off topic for StackOverFlow.

Comment: It is a code question because Im asking about flags which the batch command requires as well as how the paths works within the batch script opposed to setting it within the computers environment.