# Run batch files sequentially

Tags: batch-file, sequential

I want to ask you all how to run batch files sequentially in Windows.
I have tried :

```
start /w batchfile_1.bat 
start /w batchfile_2.bat
..
start /w batchfile_n.bat
```

but I have to close the previous .bat file process manually (e.g. by clicking) before continuing into the next one.
Is there any solution to do this automatically without me doing the manual closing previous .bat program every time?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried simply running them without `start /w`?  It's been awhile, but they should run in order, wait for each other to finish, and not open in new windows and such requiring user input.

Comment: I would check the solutions to this question: [Run Multiple batch files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071408/how-to-run-multiple-batch-files-in-serial-in-windows-command-line-environment)

Comment: @Brad: Yes, without start /w, or only using start, the .bat files will run simultaneously, not sequentially as I wanted. I have also used call, but it also make the multiple .bat files run simultaneously.

Comment: @user1634603, No, try it without using `start` or `call` at all.

Comment: Foolishly put a close vote without paying more attention to the comments. Sorry.

Answer (score 24):

I would check the solutions to this question: [Run Multiple batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071408/how-to-run-multiple-batch-files-in-serial-in-windows-command-line-environment)

- Taken from the answer in the link.

Use call:

```
call bat1.cmd
call bat2.cmd
```

By default, when you just run a batch file from another one control will not pass back to the calling one. That's why you need to use call.

Basically, if you have a batch like this:

```
@echo off
echo Foo
batch2.cmd
echo Bar
```

then it will only output

```
Foo
```

If you write it like

```
@echo off
echo Foo
call batch2.cmd
echo Bar
```

however, it will output

```
Foo
Bar
```

because after batch2 terminates, program control is passed back to your original batch file.

Comment: It's easier just to have the first batch file end by executing (not `call`ing) the second one, the second executes the third, and so forth. If you want them to be guaranteed to run in sequence, it's the only way to do it that will do so; if one crashes, it won't call the next and the execution chain will be broken.

Comment: But what happens if the OP (or anyone else) wanted to later change or add the order of the batch files. Would this way not be easier? Where all the batch files are run from one main file?

Comment: The problem is with `call` there can be an issue with one of the files in the sequence that makes it exit early, and the subsequent files will still be executed when control returns to the "main file". You can't guarantee the sequence executes strictly in order. (Not downvoting your answer, just commenting.)

Comment: Ah I see, I am kind of new to this as well so I didn't think about that. I guess this would work if the batch file order is not exactly crucial but just needs to be run at the same time. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @KenWhite "The problem with `call`..." Not if you use `EXIT /b` and check to see that the errorcode is 0 before running the next file.

Comment: @JamesK: But what if something unexpected happens before you reach `EXIT /b`? If the batch file doesn't reach that line but exits prematurely, the next `call` still executes. If you chain the batch files, that can't happen; the failure stops the next file from being executed.

Comment: @KenWhite: But if you set the errorlevel to, say 1000, at exit then if it returns with any other code you know it broke. Like `EXIT /b 1000` (I admit, I was originally thinking that the errorcode was a little more robust than it actually it.)

Comment: @JamesK: Yep, if you jump through a million loops to get there, you can do it the way you suggest; or, you could just call them sequentially as I said and not fight it. <g>

Comment: Sometimes you gots to do what you gots to do! ^_^

Comment: Please Ishikawa, Ken White, or James K, post a COMPLETE, EXACT word for word, character for character, TESTED, VERIFIED, and above all WORKING, example of the .BAT file doing what you say? If these 3 fellows are no more there, could anyone answer?  Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you are in love with using `START`, you could have your batch files end with the `EXIT` command. That will close the windows created by the `start` command.

```
@echo off
 .
 .
:: Inspired coding
 .
 .
exit
```

Comment: BTW, do not use `EXIT /b` with batch files you `START`ed. It does not close windows, and is intended to pass the errorlevel back to the calling file. Which is impossible because you launched a separate cmd.exe environment by using `START`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, using exit command indeed close the windows that appeared when I start the .bat, but the process become simultaneously executed, and not sequentially as I wanted to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but based on your comments, the following seems to be happening when you run that sequence of `START` commands:

1. A `START /W` command is invoked and starts a batch file.
2. The batch file starts executing and runs a program.
3. The batch file finishes and its console window remains open, but the program continues running.
4. The `START /W` command that was used to run the batch file is still executing because the console window remains open.
5. You wait until the program terminates, then you close the console window, and then the next `START /W` command is invoked, and everything is repeated.

Now, if you place `EXIT` at the end of every batch file you want to run sequentially, that makes situation worse because it causes the console window to close after the batch script completes, and that in turn ends the corresponding `START /W` command and causes another one to execute, even though the program invoked by the batch script may still be running. And so the effect is that the batch scripts (or, rather, the programs executed by them) run simultaneously rather than sequentially.

I think, if this can be solved at all, you need to move the `START /W` command and put it in every batch file in front of (every) command that that batch file executes and doesn't wait for the termination of. That is, if your `batchfile_1.bat` runs a `program.exe`, change the command line to `START /W program.exe`, and similarly for other relevant commands in other batch files.