# Building batch file sequentially run all exe files in the sub folers

Tags: bash, batch-file, sh

I am studying how to build batch files

> [Building a batch file to run exe files sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968287/building-a-batch-file-to-run-exe-files-sequentially)

I just read and try to understand how to run exe files sequentially .

However, I am not really sure how to run all the exe files in the subfoler.

for example, I just copied package folder from USB drive( location can be any where) 
and package folder has subfolder call drivers ( for example , /package/drivers)

and I would like to run exe files sequentially  from batch files in the main folder.

how batch file realizes currently folder and then executes all the exe files in the subfolder ?

thanks

Comment: Is this a Windows issue or a Unix issue? You say `exe` and `batch-file`, but you also have `bash` and `sh` selected. What OS is this for? Do you have a PC with BASH on it?

Answer (score 2):

In bash/sh you can use a for loop:

```
for file in /package/drivers/*.exe
do
    "$file"
done
```

Comment: You can do that if you're on Windows and you have non-exe files in your directory

Comment: In one line: `for file in /package/drivers/*.exe; do "$file"; done`

Answer (score 1):

```
find /package/drivers/ -name \*.exe -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 sh -c
```

Comment: This prints the names. It doesn't execute them. Use `-exec {} \;` for that

Comment: Indeed. I've modified commands above so that xargs will run the shell to execute the commands.