# Is it possible to bundle a list of installers (type .exe, for the windows OS), into a single executable installer?

Tags: windows-installer, installation, bundle, exe

I have a list of executables, which are installers to specific windows programs. Is it possible for me to make an installer, which bundles all these installers together in-order that the end user can install all the programs in one go, rather than individually installing the programs?

Furthermore, the programs I am referring to are open source, and I can access their source code on GitHub. In case bundling the installers is not possible, any alternative method is welcome!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make to more readable. Add code if relevant. This question seems to be opinion based which could be hard to answer.

Comment: I am aware that the question appears vague in terminology. I apologize for this. This is the most comprehensive way in which I can describe the issue currently. Moreover, I can't provide code because this is a general problem which I have to work with. Sorry!

Comment: Found a reasonable solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968287/building-a-batch-file-to-run-exe-files-sequentially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Deploying Software in General

If these are disparate and random setups that don't really belong together as a single product, you can install them in sequence even using a regular batch file - obviously. Or a normal software delivery system such as SCCM if it is for corporate deployment and use.

A central task with such sequenced approaches is to find reliable ways to run the setups silently (or to capture them and convert to MSI files) - and this can be a real challenge. If this is what you are doing - essentially just distributing a bunch of unrelated setups to a PC, then maybe have a look at these answers:

- [How to monitor and log manual installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491004/how-to-monitor-and-log-manual-installation/50493970#50493970)
- [How can I use powershell to run through an installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221983/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-run-through-an-installer/46224987#46224987)

---

### Delivering a "Shrink-Wrapped" Application (software solution)

If you need to bundle several pre-requisites with your software for delivery to end users, then market leaders **[WiX](http://www.wixtoolset.org)** (free and open source), **[Installshield](http://installshield.com)** and **[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com)** all have features for this. The commercial tools (the two latter ones) support views in the tool that will bundle standard pre-requisites in your setup.exe launcher automatically - for example the .NET Framework (which as a standard runtime these days should be downloaded via Windows Update instead of bloating your setup - in my opinion).

**[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com)** allows you to define your own files as pre- or post installation steps to include with your final `setup.exe.` [Check the feature documentation](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/exe-bootstrapper.html). And [the list of suggested learning material](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29130). [Prerequisites Page](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/prerequisites.html).

**[WiX](http://www.wixtoolset.org)** provides the **[Burn](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/)** tool to make installation bundles which can consist of MSI files, EXE files and MSP (patch) files (and whatever other files I am not aware of). It can be a bit involved to make these bundles, but it is free. You get a wrapper `setup.exe` file that then installs all the bundled elements. Here is a sample from the documentation: [How To: Install the .NET Framework Using Burn](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html).

**[Installshield](http://installshield.com)** (in the more expensive editions) provides a feature called [`Installshield Suite Projects`](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/SteCreatingSuites.htm#creatingsuites_1766868741_1049952%3FTocPath%3DCreating%2520Advanced%2520UI%2520and%2520Suite%252FAdvanced%2520UI%2520Installations%7C_____0) or `Advanced UI Projects` where you can sequence `EXE` files, `MSI` files, `AppX` files and `other files` to run in sequence. You can implement this in full GUI mode. [Here is a screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49212599/129130). Make sure to check what edition of Installshield you have, in case you can't find this feature. It might not be included in your edition. For regular setup.exe builds in normal projects there is an extensive library of normal and commonly used pre-requisites for MSI setups.

---

Some people recommend the [**dotNetInstaller Setup Bootstrapper**](http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/). I have never used it for anything real. I tried it once and found it a little weird to use. I can neither recommend it, nor say anything specific about it. No intel worth anything. Perhaps give it a try?

---

Similar Answers:

- **[How to make an installer that automatically install all the prerequisite programs for the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45477976/how-to-make-an-installer-that-automatically-install-all-the-prerequisite-program/45495822#45495822)**
- [What are some good alternatives to InstallShield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535197/what-are-some-good-alternatives-to-installshield/21863011#21863011)
- [Wix - How to run/install application without UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148875/wix-how-to-run-install-application-without-ui/48157650#48157650)
- [Wix Custom Action Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258206/wix-custom-action-sequence/49310996#49310996)
- [Regarding silent installation using Setup.exe generated using Installshield 2013 (.issuite) project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976617/regarding-silent-installation-using-setup-exe-generated-using-installshield-2013/49011371#49011371)
- [WiX alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972961/wix-alternatives/13973177#13973177)
- [Application Installer: Microsoft database engine 2010 not available under pre-requisites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359959/application-installer-microsoft-database-engine-2010-not-available-under-pre-re/48363090#48363090)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl` and download each executable to the `%temp%` folder and execute them.