# Batch file to execute programs sequentially

Tags: windows, batch-file, sequential

I have three programs, which I would like to execute sequentially. What I mean is, as soon as the first program completes its run, the second one should start and so on. I have heard that batch files can be used for this, but I am not sure exactly how to use them. Can anybody please help?
Thanks

Comment: A _similar_ question has been asked before and I bet there or lots of others that are identical. While you were typing your question several solutions had been provided by SO, one of them is still shown on the right of your post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187938/run-batch-files-sequentially?rq=1

Comment: I'm sorry, I am unfamiliar with batch files and was unsure what that question meant. I'll remove this.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can write a batch file like this:

```
@echo off  
start /wait program1.exe
start /wait program2.exe
start /wait program3.exe
```

Comment: If the programs block you can even skip the `start /wait` part

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check it out. Have a nice day!