# SQL Server 2008 R2 - sqlcmd bat file to run a batch of sql queries in folder but they are not running in order of file name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have a bunch of written sql scripts that I have written and I was looking to run as a batch in order in a folder.  After reading up I've resorted to creating a bat file which includes using the sqlcmd.  For this particular set of scripts, when i run the bat it doesn't seem to run in order.  I have no idea what is going on as I've tried renaming the sql scripts numerically with a prefix number in the beginning, tried using letters, and even renaming the whole script to just a number/letter using windows explorer.

The process might look something like this A.sql - B.sql - C.sql - D.sql - F.sql - G.sql - E.sql

Any ideas as to what I am missing or how i am renaming these files incorrectly?  Thanks

what I have in my bat file

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S W-VAN-A124178\HAZUSPLUSSRVR /d 
BC_Exposure_2016 -E -i"%%G"
pause
```

Comment: I think  you may need to run multiple bat files as pointed out here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071408/how-to-run-multiple-batch-files-in-serial-in-windows-command-line-environment) or run through sql agent

Comment: If you want to order the files, powershell might be a better (and more modern) alternative

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the output of the `dir` command which you can modify so that the files appear in alphabetical order. For that you could use `dir /A-D /B /ON`:
`/A-D` excludes directories
`/B` excludes a lot of messy additional information that is annoying to work around while parsing
`/ON` orders by name

So to modify your code:

```
for /f %%G in ('dir /A-D /B /ON') do (
  sqlcmd /S W-VAN-A124178\HAZUSPLUSSRVR /d BC_Exposure_2016 -E -i"%%G"
)
pause
```

should work. I put parenthesis around the loop. For once because I am used to it and because the code was split into two lines else.