# Why does only the first line of this Windows batch file execute but all three lines execute in a command shell?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-7

I have a batch file that executes three Maven commands, one after the other. Each command can be successfully executed in the script - by itself!. But when I add all three commands to the same file, only the first one executes before the script exits. Any idea why?

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=gdata -DartifactId=base -Dversion=1.0 -Dfile=gdata-base-1.0.jar  -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=gdata -DartifactId=blogger -Dversion=2.0 -Dfile=gdata-blogger-2.0.jar  -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=gdata -DartifactId=blogger-meta -Dversion=2.0 -Dfile=gdata-blogger-meta-2.0.jar  -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Also, if I copy all three commands and paste them into a command shell (cmd.exe), they execute one after the other with no problem. So this is apparently some issue with the dos batch file.

Comment: What a coincedent: I came here with the same problem and also the same commands in my batch file - multiple lines of "mvn install:install-file" :-D

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)*

Answer (score 363, accepted):

Maven uses batch files to do its business.  With any batch script, you must call another script using the [`call`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490873.aspx) command so it knows to return back to your script after the called script completes.  Try prepending `call` to all commands.

Another thing you could try is using the [`start`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx) command which should work similarly.

Comment: I've put `ant` inside of windows batch files before and the `call` was required to get `ant` to execute.  Without `call` the batch will stop after the first command, hence the second two not executing.  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx for more info on `call`

Comment: `start` will cause a new window to spawn, and each of the three commands will run in parallel.  If you need them to run synchronously, use `call`.

Comment: @akf: The `WAIT` option for the `start` command will cause it to wait for the program to close so it doesn't necessarily have to run in parallel.  I should have mentioned that in the beginning.

Comment: How on earth does it make sense for a scripting environment to behave this way? If I've written a script with two commands I expect the commands to be executed; I don't expect the environment to just decide to stop executing my script simply because one of those commands happens to be implemented as a script itself.

Comment: @bames53: this is a limitation that originated from DOS that carried over into modern implementations of the command prompt in Windows.  Since Microsoft's goals were to maintain backward compatibility, this is the result.

Comment: add `call pause` at the end (without quotes) if you want to keep the cmd windows open

Comment: @JinSnow, thanks. Using 'call pause' at the end is very helpful when running the script from GUI.

Comment: Similarly if running gradlew from a batch file the call prefix is required.

Answer (score 44):

Having `call` helps. However today it didn't.

This is how I solved it:

**Bat file contents** (if you want to **stop** batch when one of cmds errors)

```
cmd1 && ^
cmd2 && ^
cmd3 && ^
cmd4
```

**Bat file contents** (if you want to **continue** batch when one of cmds errors)

```
cmd1 & ^
cmd2 & ^
cmd3 & ^
cmd4
```

Comment: (The first example here is equivalent to `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 && cmd4`, essentially making all the commands one line.)

Comment: True. I wrote it that way because is a bat file, mostly you will have multiple, possibly long commands, 4 commands in a line will not be good in future maintenance. Readability is key in writing good programs and so they are on different lines.

Comment: This solution did the trick for me. The `call` solution wasn't stopping at errors, this one does.

Comment: Worked perfectly well when the command encountered an error!

Comment: Happy to know  @HarshaJK

Answer (score 22):

To execute more Maven builds from one script you shall use the Windows **call** function in the following way:

```
call mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=gdata -DartifactId=base -Dversion=1.0 -Dfile=gdata-base-1.0.jar  -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
call mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=gdata -DartifactId=blogger -Dversion=2.0 -Dfile=gdata-blogger-2.0.jar  -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
call mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=gdata -DartifactId=blogger-meta -Dversion=2.0 -Dfile=gdata-blogger-meta-2.0.jar  -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be that the particular `mvn` command `exec`s and does not return, thereby not executing the rest of the commands.

Comment: Is there a way to force the script to execute the next `mvn` command?

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the following batch file and executing it:

```
Echo one
cmd
Echo two
cmd
Echo three
cmd
```

Only the first two lines get executed. But if you type "exit" at the command prompt, the next two lines are processed. It's a shell loading another.

To be sure that this is not what is happening in your script, just type "exit" when the first command ends.

HTH!

Comment: Unlikely; Maven indeed uses a batch file which is why they need to use `call`. It's not a nested shell that isn't terminated.

Answer (score -1):

Dos commands in my batch file were running only when I type EXIT in command/DOS window. This problem solved when I removed CMD from batch file. No need of it.

Comment: well, if you explicitly open another instance (with the `cmd` command), you naturally have to `exit` it to get back to the original instance. But this has nothing to do with the question, so delete this "answer" to avoid downvoting.