# Windows batch file to install multiple perl modules - only the first line runs

Tags: windows, batch-file, activeperl, ppm

I'm installing Bugzilla on Windows, and checksetup.pl asked me to install a bunch of modules by running ppm (Perl Package Manager) commands like so:

```
C:\>ppm install TimeDate
```

This runs correctly, and installs the TimeDate module.

I haven't done much command line stuff before, but I thought this would be a good time to try it out.  So I made a batch file called PerlModules.bat:

```
ppm install Chart
ppm install Template-GD
ppm install MIME-tools
ppm install XML-Twig
ppm install PatchReader
ppm install perl-ldap
ppm install Authen-SASL
ppm install RadiusPerl
ppm install SOAP-Lite
ppm install JSON-RPC
ppm install JSON-XS
ppm install Test-Taint
ppm install HTML-Scrubber
ppm install Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper
ppm install Email-Reply
ppm install TheSchwartz
ppm install Daemon-Generic
ppm install mod_perl
ppm install Apache-SizeLimit
ppm install Math-Random-Secure
ppm install TimeDate
ppm install DateTime
ppm install DateTime-TimeZone
ppm install Template-Toolkit
ppm install Email-Send
ppm install Email-MIME
```

Running it produces this output:

```
E:\Program Files\Bugzilla>PerlModules.bat

E:\Program Files\Bugzilla>ppm install Chart
Downloading Chart-2.4.6...done
Unpacking Chart-2.4.6...done
Generating HTML for Chart-2.4.6...done
Updating files in site area...done
  18 files installed

E:\Program Files\Bugzilla>
```

So it appears that only the first line of the batch file actually runs, and the rest do nothing.

In the end I looked up the man page for ppm with `ppm help` and discovered that I could pass all the package names at once and save myself the hassle of solving this problem, but I really don't understand why my little batch file didn't work.

**I thought batch files just fed line after line to the shell prompt, waiting until each had finished its job, until they reached the end of file.  What am I missing in this equation?**

Comment: Sorry, I culled some info from my question and I appear to have missed a crucial point.  ppm is the Perl Package Manager, and it's a program that runs correctly.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Here's some info on it if you're interested:  http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.6/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html

Comment: Aaaaaand I've just now noticed this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036754/why-does-only-the-first-line-of-this-windows-batch-file-execute-but-all-three-li?rq=1  I usually check for duplicates, but I guess it was the end of a long day beating my head against a Bugzilla install.  It's not quite a duplicate because it relates to a different .bat file, but the symptoms and answer are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Perl installation the command `ppm` is a batch file: `ppm.bat` (not an  `.exe`)

When you call one batch file from another, the calling batch file is terminated *together* with the called batch file.

You need to use `call` in order to be able to run another batch file from within one batch file.

```
call ppm install Chart
call ppm install Template-GD
call ppm install MIME-tools
call ppm install XML-Twig
call ppm install PatchReader
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know if it was a .bat or not, it just installed with ActivePerl.  I'll try and let you know if this is the answer.

Comment: Just tried it, worked perfectly!  I'm now getting a bunch of "No missing packages to install", but at least that's expected since I've already installed them.  Mystery solved!