# .bat Script Terminating Before AWS Auto Scaling Commands Executed

Tags: batch-file, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I am fairly new to Amazon Cloud Auto Scaling (and AWS all together).

I am currently trying to write a .bat script that will automatically create a launch configuration and then an auto scaler. The aim is for an image that was previously set up about a week ago by a coworker.

The problem I encounter is that when I run the script, no commands past the launch configuration command is executed.

The code is here:

```
echo Beginning Auto Scale Up Process

REM Create a launch config
as-create-launch-config --image-id ami-xxxxxxx --instance-type t1.micro --user-data "Created by Launch Config reportingServerScaleUp-lc" --launch-config reportingServerScaleUp-lc 

echo Timer Complete
```

I am looking for suggestions to help me debug this issue. Or advice on how to solve it. After the "echo Timer Complete" I have a command to create an auto scaler. Though, not even the "echo Timer Complete" is executed. The console does return indicating that the launch configuration is created though :)

Also, when I enter each command sequentially into the command line, each executes perfectly. The launch configuration is created as is the auto scale group.

Comment: Perhaps the `as-create-launch-config` is triggering an `exit` somehow.  Is there any difference if you prefix that line with `cmd.exe` to launch it in another shell?

Comment: you are exactly right, friend. I just added my fix in the answers. I added "call" to each aws command.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that the AWS commands call exit which exits the .bat script prematurely.

Prepending each AWS command with "call" did the trick.

I found suggestions in this question: *[Why does only the first line of this Windows batch file execute but all three lines execute in a command shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036754/why-does-only-the-first-line-of-this-windows-batch-file-execute-but-all-three-li)*