# How to call SCons from a Windows Batch subroutine?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scons

I am trying to write a .bat file that executes a few SCons commands, but I found that once the first executes, the bash closes without executing the others.

So I made a sub-routine and use the CALL command:

```
call :my_subroutine
pause
exit /b

:my_subroutine
    scons platform=windows -c
    exit /b
```

While this subroutine executes correctly with a `echo "test"` inside, as soon as I put the scons command, the console says it can't find the command file named `my_subroutine`...

```
D:\...\godot>call :my_subroutine

D:\...\godot>scons platform=windows -c
Le système ne trouve pas le nom de fichier de commandes - my_subroutine

D:\...\godot>pause
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

Messages in english:

```
The system doesn't finds the name of the commands file - my_subroutine
[...]
Press a key to continue...
```

Comment: Can you translate the messages above into english? Especially the one right after it calls scons?

Comment: I translated in the first post.

Comment: is scons.bat in your PATH ?

Comment: Yes, and it works without using a subroutine.

Comment: What if you put full path to and include the .bat extension?

Comment: Writing `"C:\Python27\scons.bat" platform=windows -c` makes no difference, the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try using call scons platform=windows -c

Comment: Hint: You can format code as code by enclosing it in `\`\`` or by indenting it with four spaces to make your post more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is because windows it trying to skip to a `:my_subroutine` subroutine in `scons.bat`.

The situation can be reproduced with the following pair of batch files:

**test.bat**

```
rem test.bat :start

call :my_subroutine
exit /b

:my_subroutine
   rem test.bat :my_subroutine
   test2
   exit /b
```

**test2.bat**

```
rem test2.bat :start

exit /b

:my_subroutine
    rem test2.bat :my_subroutine
    echo wtf
```

That produce the following output:

```
>test
>rem test.bat :start
>call :my_subroutine
>rem test.bat :my_subroutine
>test2
>rem test2.bat :my_subroutine
>echo wtf
wtf
>exit /b
```

---

The call help page states:

> CALL command now accepts labels as the target of the CALL.  The syntax
>   is:
>
> ```
> CALL :label arguments
> ```
>
> A new batch file context is created with the specified arguments and
>   control is passed to the statement after the label specified.

It appears that this behaviour continues even after invoking a separate batch file.

---

To invoke scons.bat from your batch file bypassing this gotcha the solution is (as Guillermo Meza Lopez says) to use call:

```
call scons platform=windows -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make this work is to explicitly call the python script.

```
python <path to scons.py> platform=windows -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Found how to fix this in this thread : [Why does only the first line of this Windows batch file execute but all three lines execute in a command shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036754/why-does-only-the-first-line-of-this-windows-batch-file-execute-but-all-three-li)

For instance if you have build32.bat and build64.bat, your bat file to build all should look like this :

```
build32.bat & ^
build64.bat
```

If you want to stop running in case of error, use && ^ instead of & ^.