# Command Line Script Ends After Webpack CLI

Tags: webpack, command-line

I have a simple command script which looks like this:

```
webpack --config dev.webpack.config.js
consoleapp.exe param1 param2
```

I'm running it via Visual Studio (2019, Community) Task Runner.
I can see from the console that Webpack runs and succeeds (and indeed the output js is created and works fine).
However `consoleapp.exe` does not run.
The last line in the output is

```
modules by path ./*.js 1.46 KiB
  ./formbuild.js 190 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./Form.js 1.27 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.11.0 compiled successfully in 171 ms
Process terminated with code 0.
```

Why is the console app not run?

Answer (score 0):

As per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036754/why-does-only-the-first-line-of-this-windows-batch-file-execute-but-all-three-li), you need to use [call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call) for control to return to you script.

So for me, that meant changing the above to:

```
call webpack --config dev.webpack.config.js
call consoleapp.exe param1 param2
```