# Looping a batch file that calls another batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My embedded C compiler generates a batch file to run various build outputs in a processor simulator from the command line. I'd like to create a batch file to call that auto generated batch file that is somewhere convenient, and I'd like to be able to rerun it just by clicking a key as often as I want all day long.

Here's what I've tried

```
cd "C:\foo\project name\settings\"
:repeat
cls
"Project Name.Unit Test Ouput.cspy.bat" & pause
goto repeat
```

I see the output I expect from the batch file, followed by a:

> Press any key to continue . . .

When I press enter the script ends and never executes the goto.
If I remove the pause statement the script just ends immediately.
If I type & goto repeat the script still ends immediately.

CDing to the batch file from the command line, running it, and then click the up arrow and enter effectively does what I want... I am trying to automate it a tiny bit more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825746/cmd-exe-when-to-use-call-to-run-external-programs

Comment: Adding call in front of the batch file call worked like a champ! Can you please post that as the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a batch file from another batch file, you have to use the `call` statement.  If you don't, then your outer batch file will end when the inner one does.

```
call "Project Name.Unit Test Ouput.cspy.bat" & pause
```