# Error in executing Abaqus from command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, abaqus

I am using a student version 6.17-4 of abaqus. I would like to call my input file which is created in MATLAB using .bat(batch file) and I create a .bat file in MATLAB with given below information

```
call abq6174 job=Data.inp, interactive ask_delete=off
```

where data.inp is my input file.To open my input file in Abaqus using a command in CMD.exe, I use below code

```
call abq6174 job=Data.inp
```

I type the above command in CMD.exe. I have also checked and rectified my environment variables but despite of that i get below error every time in CMD.exe.

CMD result:

> ```
> C:\Users\maste\oneDrive\Documents\MATLAB>call abq6174 job =Data.inp
>
> 'abq6174' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
> ```

Comment: What's `abq6174`? Is the a MATLAB file or something else?

Comment: @SteveFest ..abq6174 refers to "abaqus version 6.17-4" .... I'm sorry..It is command prompt :)

Comment: Is `abaqus version 6.17-4` a MATLAB code or something?

Comment: `CALL` is only used to call a subroutine or a batch file, so I don't think you call external MATLAB code like this.

Comment: Abaqus is another software used for Finite element methods..  I write a code in Matlab and generate .inp file which can be opened in Abaqus.

Comment: So, you should only do `abq6174 job = blah blah`.

Comment: Yes, i should use "call abq6174 job =Data.inp " but however i cannot implement it as it throws an error

Comment: oh.. Yes you have replaced the error observed as a text . I cannot get the reason for the error

Comment: Try replacing `abq6174` with the actual `exe` program path you wish to open the file with, like `"C:/Program Files/<Abaqus install location>/abaqus.exe"`

Comment: It still gives same error :(

Comment: This problem seems not to be related to matlab, please remove that tag if so. See [ask].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825746/cmd-exe-when-to-use-call-to-run-external-programs

Comment: Thanks :) I got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to call Abaqus from the system shell directly (not from a script or batch file), you should simply remove the word `call`. Begin the analysis by calling Abaqus directly and passing it the name of your input file, as shown below:

```
C:\Work\MyJob>abaqus job=Data
```

It is possible that on your system Abaqus must be called using some alternative form like `abq6174`, which specifies the major, minor, and update versions for your installation, but that should only be necessary if you have more than one version installed.

If this does not work, then it is unlikely that the Abaqus commands directory is on your system PATH, and you must add `C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\Commands` to your PATH environment.

You can find much more info about how to call abaqus, along with a multitude of command line options, from the official docs. Try reading through *Abaqus Analysis Users Manual>Introduction, Spatial Modeling, and Execution>Job Execution>Execution Procedures>Abaqus/Standard, Abaqus/Explicit, and Abaqus/CFD execution.* In my installation that is Section 3.2.2.