# call batch script without CALL or START

Tags: windows, batch-file

what does it mean when I call batch script from batch script without `CALL` or `START`?

example. I have two scripts a.bat and b.bat

**a.bat**:

```
echo I am A >> log
b.bat
echo end of A >> log
```

**b.bat**:

```
echo I am B >> log
sleep 1
echo end of B >> log
```

after execution of a.bat i see in the **log**:

```
I am A 
I am B 
end of B
```

Where is message "end of A" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end of message `a.bat` is never reached because when you call another batch file without `start` or `call` it transfers control over to that batch, and never returns.

If you wanted it to return to the calling batch, you would use `call`, or you could use `start` but that would start another instance of cmd (unless you use the `/b` switch).

Comment: Actually even `start /B` starts a new `cmd` instance (check in Windows Task Manager), but no new window is created...