# Poor man's remote job execution in windows 7 using job scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Okay, I know my title is a bit obscure but let me explain what I did and how I failed to accomplish what I wanted to do.

First off, security is not a my concern at this moment. Once I get it working I will implement an authentication schema to protect my setup.

I want my windows machine at home, to ftp/scp a batch file from a Linux server on the cloud (A VPS with non-root user playing ftp/scp server role) and run it as soon as it completes downloading it.

I setup a non-privileged (read as non-root) account on my vps. I generated a public/private key pair. From my windows PC, using the key-pair I was able to login to my VPS without needing a password. Using the same key-pair, I was able to download a file from my VPS onto windows machine.

I have a batch file that I scheduled to run every 3 minutes using the windows' internal task scheduler. Batch file does something like this :

```
scp remote-server:/home/user1/job.bat .
job.bat  > outfile.txt
scp outfile.txt user1@remote-server:/home/user1/outfile.txt
echo "rem done" > job.bat
scp job.bat user1@remote-server:/home/user1/job.bat
```

last two lines are there to protect against unintentional run of the same batch twice.

when it runs, if pulls the batch file from the remote-server but fails to execute it as the subsequent line and the batch file dies without going any further than the first line.

The reason I am looking for something like this is two fold. 1) when I can I access to my laptop, using VNC, but sometimes, it goes unresponsive and I have no other way to take back control but killing VNC process and restarting from the command line;m 2) when I am bandwidth limited, I'd like to run a nircmd command to take a screenshot and send it to me via scp, so that I can follow up, what's going on at home.

Can someone shed a light, why I am in this shape, i.e., why my batch file gets stuck after first line ? More importantly, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Do you receive any errors? How does the batch file fail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [call batch script without CALL or START](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586164/call-batch-script-without-call-or-start)

Comment: @unclemeat : no error messages encountered

Comment: @HarryJohnston : tried with running the batch file directly and using call command, but the result is the same. job.bat won't run

Comment: What is inside job.bat? Your code overwrites it and then updates the batch file in vps with only the `rem done`. On next run `job.bat` will do nothing.

Comment: @MCND job.bat changes. I can update it from anywhere on my linux VPS at any given time to make my laptop do whatever I want at that time. So, its contents are irrelevant at this point. But for testing, I wanted it to execute a benign single liner, something like `echo "testing" > c:\test.out`

Comment: Is `scp` a console tool, a windows tool or a batch file?

Comment: scp is the renamed version of putty's pscp and it is an executable, i.e., scp.exe, needless to say, it is an executable to run under windows command prompt.

Comment: I'm not sure offhand if batch files with Linux end-of-line sequences will run or not.  You might need to download it in text mode.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I do not create the batch files on the linux side. I use a windows PC at work, save it as job.bat and upload to my VPS, to be picked up by my home laptop. VPS is just an intemediary.

Comment: Is `scp` exiting?  There was another question recently about a problem caused by `pscp` hanging on exit.  Perhaps try putting an echo command in the batch file instead of the call to `job.bat`, or monitor `scp.exe` using Task Manager while submitting a job.bat?

Answer (score 0):

Try using schtask in your batch file to dynamically create a new scheduled task and then run that task to implement your down loaded script separately at the end of this task.

look at schtasks /Create /? and schtasks /Run /?.  examples should help (the freecell example will be the closest to what you want, just remove the time constraints options.)