# Is it possible to call multiple batch files at once from a batch file?

Tags: variables, batch-file

So, i need to call multiple batch files, each containing one variable, all at once, so i can activate multiple variables at once.

Can you help me? If it is possible, what's the code for it?

Answer (score 2):

just have to: `CALL another_file.bat`

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to have them called and runned at once, in one window?

Comment: In Windows 10, the command that works for me is this: `start "Window title" /wait cmd /k call something.bat`. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12136538/3380951)