# Why the .bat file skips lines and jumps to the end?

Tags: java, android, ant, batch-file

My .bat file is as follows:

```
@echo on
cd %1\%2
copy D:\source\Meep\bat\ant.properties .\
android update project -p .\ 
ant clean
ant release
```

When I start the bat file, it ran correctly up to the line `android update project -p .\` and then it jumped to the end skipping the lines `ant clean` and `ant release`.

Following were printed out in the console:

```
D:\>cd D:\source\Meep\Meep\trunk\MeepApp

D:\source\Meep\Meep\trunk\MeepApp>copy D:\source\Meep\bat\ant.properties .\
已复制         1 个文件。

D:\source\Meep\Meep\trunk\MeepApp>android update project -p .\
Updated local.properties
Updated file D:\source\Meep\Meep\trunk\MeepApp\proguard-project.txt

D:\source\Meep\Meep\trunk\MeepApp>
```

Why is that? And please tell me how to run the whole bat commands. Thanks very much.

Note: it ran OK when I entered commands on CMD one by one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`android` is a .bat file and invoking a .bat from another without stopping the first one requires `call`:

```
call android update project -p .\
```

More information: [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

Comment: Year. ant clean and ant release needs to require "call", too.

Comment: mvn clean compile install also needs call , thanks a lot @laalto