# How to run several yiic commands in one .bat file?

Tags: csv, batch-file, import, yii, yiic

I have an `ImportCommand class` which reads a file and imports the data from that file to a database. The command itself works fine.

However, I need to run the same command several times with different files.

**My .bat file:**

```
@echo off
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\protected\
yiic import c:\sourcefiles\users_1.csv
yiic import c:\sourcefiles\users_2.csv
yiic import c:\sourcefiles\users_3.csv
```

The first command runs then the script stops and files users_2.csv and users_3.csv are not processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with this for a while, I found this answer: [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

So the .bat file should be:

```
@echo off
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\protected\`
call yiic import c:\sourcefiles\users_1.csv
call yiic import c:\sourcefiles\users_2.csv
call yiic import c:\sourcefiles\users_3.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CALL` command. Without `CALL`, control is transferred to other batch and is not returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@echo off
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\protected\
yiic import c:\sourcefiles\users_1.csv && yiic import c:\sourcefiles\users_2.csv && yiic import c:\sourcefiles\users_3.csv
```

This will execute the desired command one by one . It only proceeds one operation is successful.