# How to execute multiple batch files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, execute

I need to execute several batch files one after another, each .bat executing from a different folder. for example I have the following code:

```
cd test1
oneup.bat
cd test2
oneup.bat
cd test3
oneup.bat
```

When I execute that code inside the folder containing test1,2 and 3, It executes the first oneup.bat within the test1 folder but then it stops. How can I make it run as intended?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /d "test1"
call oneup.bat
set a="%cd%"
cd /d "test2"
call "%a%\oneup.bat"
cd /d "test3"
call "%a%\oneup.bat"
```

this will exec the same batch file in different folders.

Comment: This needs the call keyword or it will stop after the 2nd line.

Comment: Thanks guys, but still not working. It stops after it executes the first oneup.bat file

Comment: inside the test1 folder

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /d "test1"
call oneup.bat
cd /d "test2"
call oneup.bat
cd /d "test3"
call oneup.bat
```