# How do I open another batch file multiple times?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm wondering how I can open a batch file with another batch file multiple times
I'm currently using this code

```
set counter=0
:loop
call Pinger.bat
SET /A counter=%counter%+1
if %counter% GTR 100
    (GOTO exit) 
else 
    (GOTO loop)
:exit
exit
```

But it just closes the bat file with this code as soon as the first one of the other one is opened..

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file.

Comment: @zyboxinternational: Wrong; he used `call`.

Comment: @SLaks Which is what the accepted answer for that question uses, meaning it's a duplicate. malach's answer also applies to the case of user 3528008's question.

Comment: @zyboxinternational: Huh? He's already doing that, and it's still not working.

Comment: @SLaks They aren't doing what malach mentioned in his answer, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Why isn't `call` working here?

Comment: I have no idea why call isn't working.. It opens the Pinger file and then it stops, I've already looked at the link above and I couldn't find the answer..

Comment: seems like `Pinger.bat` has an `exit` command.  remove that and it should work.  Or try `start /wait cmd /c call Pinger.bat`

Comment: I don't see any exit command in the Pinger.bat file?

color 02 
ping <ip> -t -l 1500

Comment: Fixed it, used start /k call Pinger.bat

Comment: `for /L %%i in (1,1,100) do call Pinger.bat` or `for /L %%i in (1,1,100) do start Pinger.bat`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong on the `if` statement, see the fixed version below:

```
set counter=0
:loop
call Pinger.bat
SET /A counter=%counter%+1
if %counter% GTR 100 (
    GOTO exit 
) else (
    GOTO loop
)
:exit
exit
```

Comment: I didn't change anything, still the same thing

Comment: Pinger.bat never finishes with ping -t