# running bat file inside bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

The script after fourth line does not run. If i comment out the fourth line, all commands work. I think script switches to dx.bat file and does not return to caller bat. Here is the script:

```
set ref_path=C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\

cd C:\android-sdk\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2
dx.bat --dex --verbose --core-library --output=%ref_path%classes.zip %ref_path%tmp\classes

cd C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\

7z x C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\SP.war -oC:\Users\xyz\Desktop\SP -r -y
```

How can I make this script work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, calling a batch file from inside another does *not* return execution to the parent after the child is finished running.

To change this and get the expected behavior you need to use the `CALL` command:

```
CALL dx.bat ...parameters...
```