# Run a command promt and run a command

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a command which is calling other command prompt of Oracle and running a command on it. Currently, I am running it using below command

```
D:\Oracle\setenv.bat /k  BuildApp
```

But it only runs setenv.bat and quits and doesn't run `BuildApp`. `BuildApp` is to run on a command prompt opened by `setenv.bat`. Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: `call d:\Oracle\setenv.bat /k BuildApp`

Comment: see also this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file

Answer (score 0):

Try `CMD /c d:\Oracle\setenv.bat /k BuildApp`.