# batch file not running completely

Tags: batch-file

I have below batch file

```
cd C:\batchTest\a\a-app
mvn dependency:tree > a.txt
cd C:\batchTest\b\b-app
mvn dependency:tree > b.txt
```

while running it is giving below output

```
    C:\batchTest>abcd
    C:\batchTest>cd C:\batchTest\a\a-app
    C:\batchTest\a\a-app>mvn dependency:tree  1>a.txt
    C:\batchTest\a\a-app>
```

it is not running last two commands.
What is missing here?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

`mvn` is a bat file  - [so you you need to invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file) it like `call mvn..` :

```
@echo off
cd C:\batchTest\a\a-app
call mvn dependency:tree > a.txt
cd C:\batchTest\b\b-app
call mvn dependency:tree > b.txt
```