# exit node.js cmd after starting it by batch

Tags: node.js, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, exit

I've got two batch files that I want to call and let them close by themselves.
In the first, I'm updating a package via npm and after updating, it should pack a vsix extension. The Problem: after calling npm, the whole rest of the batch-file is ignored. Does anybody have a workaround for this?

First file:

```
@echo off
start /wait nodejs.cmd|echo n>nul
tfx extension create --manifest-globs src\vss-extension.json
```

Second file (nodejs.cmd):

```
npm i -g tfx-cli
exit
```

Thanks in advance ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm` is a cmd file.[Try with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file):

```
call npm i -g tfx-cli
exit
```