# Automated running .bat with commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a automated.bat with the following lines:

```
cd C:\Users\user\Downloads\megatools-1.9.97-win64\megatools-1.9.97-win64\
megacmd.bat
megals /Root --username username@email.domain --password password
megamkdir /Root/testmake2 --username username@email.domain --password password
```

It will happily say the megacmd.bat is Megatools Shell, but then it won't excecute the commands that follow.

I figured it might be because the megacmd.bat is in a different programming language, hence the incomming commands aren't valid.

So I tried to fit it all in 1 line with:

```
cd C:\Users\a\Downloads\megatools-1.9.97-win64\megatools-1.9.97-win64\
megacmd.bat & megals /Root --username username@email.domain --password password & megamkdir /Root/testmake2 --username username@email.domain --password password
```

but that didn't do anything with the commands either so I also tried:

```
cd C:\Users\a\Downloads\megatools-1.9.97-win64\megatools-1.9.97-win64\
megacmd.bat & "megals /Root --username username@email.domain --password password" & "megamkdir /Root/testmake2 --username username@email.domain --password password"
```

And

```
cd C:\Users\a\Downloads\megatools-1.9.97-win64\megatools-1.9.97-win64\
megacmd.bat "megals /Root --username username@email.domain --password password" & "megamkdir /Root/testmake2 --username username@email.domain --password password"
```

And

```
cd C:\Users\a\Downloads\megatools-1.9.97-win64\megatools-1.9.97-win64\
megacmd.bat megals /Root --username username@email.domain --password password & megamkdir /Root/testmake2 --username username@email.domain --password password
```

But I can't seem to get the syntax right. What would be the command to have the megacmd.bat run and execute the above 2 commands consecutively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 0):

your line

```
megacmd.bat
```

starts `megacmd.bat` and gives control to it. It never returns to your `automated.bat`.

You should

```
call megacmd.bat
```

to return control to your first `.bat` after `megacmd.bat` finishes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed I now realise the control was not in hands of the command file anymore, meaning the "parameters" or inputs were not passed along.  
  
However, even when I launch:  
  `cd C:\Users\user\Downloads\megatools-1.9.97-win64\megatools-1.9.97-win64\`<br/>
    `call megacmd.bat megals /Root --username username@email.domain --password password`<br/>
<br/>
The batch file will not excecute the command. It appears I can't figure out how to pass along more than 1 command consecutively.

Comment: are `megals` and `megamkdir` also batchfiles? Then you have to `call` them too. If your first four code lines run fine when you enter them on command line, then this will probably work.

Comment: Dear Stephan, thank you for your suggestion, they were .exe files. 
However instead of trying to pass these commands along to the megacmd.bat, I figured I might be more successful at manipulating the batch file so that it would simply run with the commands encoded. And thanks to this wonderful community, I was :)

Comment: Yeah - I read your other question. The `@cmd` opened a new instance of the interpreter using the same window, but that was not aware of any following commands, because they stayed within the old instance.