# Use Batch File to Run Multiple console applications

Tags: batch-file

I am new to using batch files so forgive me if I say something incorrect

I am trying to run multiple console applications (same name) at the same time (in different directories) using a batch file. Right now it runs one console application, then runs the other (after the first is finished). Is it possible to run multiple at the same time?

This is the syntax I have been using, with different directories

```
cd "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Folder 1\
Application.exe
cd "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Folder 2\
Application.exe
cd "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Folder 3\
Application.exe
etc...
```

Also, another question: If i wanted to pause X seconds between every 2 applications what would I add?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the 'Start' keyword to run multiple .exe "at the same time".
Try using the 'Wait' keyword giving the alotted amount of seconds between runtimes.