# Second command in a batch file does not run

Tags: batch-file, rspec

I have a .bat file which runs two rspec commands

```
rspec --pattern F:\giza\coreui\runtime_regression\featuresets\Grid\Grid\Actions\spec\*_spec.rb --format html > F:\output_chrome.html
rspec --pattern F:\giza\coreui\runtime_regression\featuresets\Grid\Grid\Actions\spec\*_spec.rb --format html > F:\output_firefox.html
```

However, the second command does not execute.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What error messages are you seeing for the second command?

Comment: Nothing..The first command runs all the rspec tests (mentioned in the suite).After the execution is over, the second command is just skipped without throwing any errors.   I am using java code to create and run the batch file..I am not sure that this matters here,though..appreciate your help..:)

Comment: Is rspec an exe file or batch file? Try to add CALL before your commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Probably rspec is a batch file and that's why only one is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file).Try with:

```
call rspec --pattern F:\giza\coreui\runtime_regression\featuresets\Grid\Grid\Actions\spec\*_spec.rb --format html > F:\output_chrome.html
call rspec --pattern F:\giza\coreui\runtime_regression\featuresets\Grid\Grid\Actions\spec\*_spec.rb --format html > F:\output_firefox.html
```

Comment: That, dear sir/madam, was a stroke of genius..:)  worked like a charm