# Run ipython notebook in different anaconda environment (in script)

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, ipython, anaconda

I want to change environment to `py34` and run ipython notebook using a script.

Entering in command mode line by line
1) `activate py34`
2) `jupyter notebook`
does the trick. However, since I need to do this so frequently I want to make a script that does the same (on Windows 7).

A script containing ONLY `jupyter notebook` works (launches browser with http://localhost:8888/tree open and python kernel), however script containing both lines:

```
activate py34
jupyter notebook
```

does not. It simply closes the command window. Could you, please, tell how to modify the script to make it running in py34 environment as in line-by-line command mode?

Comment: I could bet that the `activate` program is an `activate.bat` Batch file! Just precede it with `call` command: `call activate py34`

Comment: Thanks! This actually solves the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Aacini's comment, this is the working bat-file:

```
call activate py34
jupyter notebook
```