# How to install android apk using batchfile

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I am working on hybrid application for that every time i have to move some files from some place to assets in android application,so for this i wrote batch file.If i execute line by line command in command prompt it is working but if run batch file it is stopping before installing apk in device.

commands:

```
D:
cd D:\NewFolder\SampleApp
gradlew.bat assembleDebug
cd D:\NewFolder\SampleApp\app\build\outputs\apk
adb -d install  app-debug.apk
```

Comment: is your device rooted?

Comment: no i am installing in non rooted device

Comment: try a rooted device,for installing apk without user's knowledge.

Comment: if i execute commands one by one in command prompt it is working,i don't know why it is not running if create batch file and run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are running in multiple batch files in batch file,we should use call
for gradlew.bat assembleDebug,
Actually it is closing command prompt so that remaining commands are not executing.

```
commands:

D:
cd D:\NewFolder\SampleApp
call gradlew.bat assembleDebug
cd D:\NewFolder\SampleApp\app\build\outputs\apk
adb -d install  app-debug.apk
```