# Execute a batch file from another batch while keeping previous console open

Tags: batch-file

I want to execute a batch file from another batch file and I have been successful in doing so but the problem is once the 2nd batch is executed the 1st batch window closes. I want to keep the first batch window to stay open

The command I am using is :

1st.bat :

```
2nd.bat "path"

pause
```

Comment: try `call 2nd.bat "path"`

Comment: There is no 1st and 2nd console (batch) window in your approach; calling `2nd.bat` like you do runs that file in the *same* console window (context), but when finished, execution does *not return* to `1st.bat`, unless you use the `call` command like this: `call 2nd.bat "path"`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

Comment: thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
start "windowname" "file.bat"
```

Sorry if this doesn't work; I'm currently using a mobile phone.