# Why does command prompt script close when checking npm version?

Tags: node.js, batch-file, cmd, npm, command-prompt

I have a file **npm_version.cmd** that does not pause and instead closes the window:

```
npm -v
@pause
```

I have a similar file **nodejs_version.cmd** that does pause and keeps the window open:

```
node -v
@pause
```

It seems npm is changing the window to npm and then back to cmd or something.

Any idea how to force this to pause?

Comment: I assume `npm` is a batch file, sou you need to state `call npm` for the execution to return to your calling batch file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bceause npm itself is a bat (or cmd) file.

try with :

```
call npm -v
```

you are hitting [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)