# Windows cmd script stops after ng build?

Tags: angular, cmd, ng-build

I am trying to run `ng build` in a Windows `cmd` script. I can't seem to get the script to continue after the `ng build` command.

Example `test.cmd` (in an Angular project directory of course):

```
ng build
echo Done. > done.txt
```

I get the output from the `ng build` as expected, but I never get the `done.txt` file. Anyone know how to get the script to continue past `ng build`?

Answer (score 1):

According to @npocmaka's answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39527875/19380738). npm or ng itself is a bat (or cmd) file.
So you can write your cmd code like this:

```
@echo off
call npm run build
echo Done. > done.txt
pause
```