# Activate virtual environement and start jupyter notebook all in batch file

Tags: python, windows, cmd, jupyter-notebook, conda

I created the following batch file: `jupyter_nn.bat`. 
Inside file I have:

```
cd "C:\My_favorite_path"
activate neuralnets
jupyter notebook
```

So the goal is to activate conda virtual environment and start jupyter notebook. For some reason this does not work. Window immediately shuts down. If I run this batch file from cmd, it only executes `activate neulranets`. I already tried `pause` and `pause>nul` and other voodoo dances. Any suggestions? Also this is for Windows 7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add `CALL` before the activate. Since `activate` is another batch script, unless you `CALL` it, the whole process will exit. See here for more explanation: [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103994/2449192)

```
cd "C:\My_favorite_path"
CALL activate neuralnets
jupyter notebook
```

(You might also need to `CALL` the Jupyter Notebook)

Comment: Thank you very much! No need to `CALL` Jupyter Notebook.