# Why does my batch script stop after activating a new conda env?

Tags: batch-file, conda, miniconda

This is enough to reproduce the issue:

Save as `test.bat`

```
:: Create Conda env
set name=%1
conda create -n %name% python -y
activate %name%
echo "Never gets here"
:: script should continue below...
```

Run from cmd.

```
>test.bat "testname"
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Jamie\git>test.bat testname

C:\Users\Jamie\git>set name=testname

C:\Users\Jamie\git>conda create -n testname python -y
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\Jamie\Miniconda2\envs\testname:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    pip:            9.0.1-py27_1
    python:         2.7.13-0
    setuptools:     27.2.0-py27_1
    vs2008_runtime: 9.00.30729.5054-0
    wheel:          0.29.0-py27_0

#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate testname
#
# To deactivate this environment, use:
# > deactivate testname
#
# * for power-users using bash, you must source
#


C:\Users\Jamie\git>activate testname

(testname) C:\Users\Jamie\git>
```

And that's it. The `echo` statement doesn't execute, but there is no error message.

Why does activating the conda env halt the batch script, and is there a way around it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activate virtual environement and start jupyter notebook all in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353108/activate-virtual-environement-and-start-jupyter-notebook-all-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

use

```
call activate %name%
```

- I'm assuming that `activate` is a batch file. If you `call` it, processing will return after that batch is finished. Without the `call`, execution is transferred to `activate` and ends when `activate` ends.

Comment: I need to be in the environment to continue

Comment: @JamieBull With respect to Conda, `being in an environment` is basically having ~4 environment variables set. If you use `CALL`, the environment variables set by the activate batch file will be retained on return.  See: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/Rd5AW3qrqxXkTCt6Ma7Qx15M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=/raw

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comment by asker @Jamie Bull himself.

> I need to be in the environment to continue

In my case, to describe it more precisely, how could I activate a CONDA ENV, change to a working directory directly in one-click, or in one-command?

From a Linux background, we are more likely to complete this request by a simple one-line BASH script. I was facing the same problem with BAT file, as discussed here, CMD batch file's behavior is not that suitable for this task. Using CALL directive within BAT does not help either.

Luckily, CONDA now is packaged with PowerShell's PS1 start script, and the according shortcut left me with another choice, after a few test, it works.

My final solution is to create a Windows shortcut for my purpose, i.e, open PyTorch ENV or Tensorflow ENV in one click. I just made a copy of CONDA's package shortcut, did the edit on the copy itself, than the edited shortcut is ready to use. The screenshot will explain it well.

[image: windows shortcut for CONDA ENV activate]

For PS1 script, it is finally as easy as BASH now:

```
# tf_env.ps1: Activate ENV and go to working directory
conda activate tf-gpu
cd C:\Tensorflow.Playground
```

Answer (score -2):

try adding a new line at the end of your `.bat` file

Comment: That´s not actually the end, just in the example. I'll edit to make that clear

Comment: ah, you're right. to think of it - it can't possibly continue executing - since you've started a new shell session. It's same with ssh. Imagine you do

    `run-locally.sh`
   `ssh remote@server`
    `run-on-the-remote-server.sh`

remote command would never execute, because it will give you back control once it's logged in

Comment: you can't use `activate` (as I imagine), but you can call any python binary (you can use binary from virtual env directly) - no need to run "activate"

Comment: Ah, yes. I don't actually need to activate the env until the very end of my script. Thanks, I think it's sorted now

Comment: but if there was a solution - it would look something like this. `conda activate EVN_NAME --execute second_part_of_the_script.bat`

Comment: yeah - I don't think it's possible, sorry for giving you a wrong idea. What I meant to say by that "what if", is that whatever happens after `activate`, should be somehow passed as a script at that stage. But that's probably impossible.

Comment: I've gone with making two scripts. the first leaves me in the env, then the second does the rest, and still reduces my typing considerably!