# Running VSCode from batch file stops execution

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to open two VSCode projects from a batch file, and then close the batch file and let the VSCode run.

Tried several methods:

This does not close the batch file, and if I close it by my self, VSCode terminates:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" c:\project1
start "" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" c:\project2
exit
```

This one opens two cmds, each one opens VSCode and then terminates, but often it also holds and does not close for some reason:

```
start cmd /c "code c:\project1 && exit"
start cmd /c "code c:\project2 && exit"
```

Simply running VSCode sometimes holds the execution of the next commands altogether:

```
code c:\project1
code c:\project2
.
.  <-- Next commands don't run
.
```

So how should I open VSCode in a way that will not stop the execution and will not depend on the terminal remaining open?

Comment: have you tried without start? `cmd /c "code c:\project1 && exit"
`

Comment: Tried it now. Doesn't work. It continues executing all the next commands but does not exit from the main batch file even if there is an "exit" command

Comment: Always put the (empty) pair of quotes behind `start`, like `start "" cmd /c ...`, because the first quoted string might be interpreted as a window title rather than something else...

Comment: @aschipf Tried it also, doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

add **call** before

```
call code C:/proyect1
call code C:/proyect2
```

I've answer this in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75717355/16513233): The file run by "code ." is not really an executable but a .cmd/.bat. As discused in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file). Running one batch script within another without call will stop execution

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is more than 2 years old now, but I was facing this problem right now and just found out the solution.

Try calling `code.exe` directly instead the `code.cmd` that is in system path.

```
"%localappdata\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" C:\project1
"%localappdata\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" C:\project2
exit
```