# My batch script stops execution after the code . command

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-code, command-prompt

Here is my simple batch script:

```
d:
cd D:/test_folder/test_project
start chrome -incognito http://localhost:19002
code .
expo start
```

the script only executes up to the `code .` line and then gives me a prompt. expo start is never run. What could be the problem? How can I continue the execution after the `code .` line?

**EDIT:**
If I remove the `code .` line, the file works as intended.

Comment: If you close `code`, once it has opened, it should also work! Your issue is that you're not closing `code`, or your command needs to be modified if you want to run the `expo` line before `code` has been closed. Why not use `start` again?

Comment: Batch files execute each line of code to its completion before moving on to execute the next line of code. As you can see in your current code, using the `START` command resolves that issue otherwise `CODE` would never execute because it would be waiting for `CHROME` to finish executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through a lot of posts, I found out that the way to open vs code is:

```
d:
cd D:/test_folder/test_project
start chrome -incognito http://localhost:19002
start "" code D:/test_folder/test_project
expo start
```

This works as required.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **call**:

```
call code .
```

The file run by "code ." is not really an executable but a .cmd/.bat. As discused in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file). Running one batch file within another without **call** will stop execution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of VaibhavJoshi almost worked for me: a new `cmd` is started before the script ends, and I don't want this.

On my side, `where code` yields two results:

```
C:\> where code
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd
```

To prevent a new `cmd` to be started on `start "" code`, I had to use the `.exe` directly:

```
set vscode="%localappdata%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"

rem some other stuff ...

start "" %vscode% --folder-uri vscode-remote://ssh-remote+10.3.3.3/path/to/my/project
```

Worked like a charm, for local and remote projects.