# Batch self duplication

Tags: batch-file

How to make a batch program duplicate itself to a different folder?

I tied this but it did not delete the move file:

```
echo copy script.bat F:\ > move.bat

move.bat

del move.bat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only this:

```
copy "%~f0" "F:\"
```

See more about the parameter expansion [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).The reason why your code didn't worked because you hadn't used `call` when you were executing `move.bat` (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)). And it is a bad idea to name your bats on already existing commands because at some point you can't know what exactly will be executed.