# How to maintain environment variables of a bat file before executing another program in a bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-tool

[A way to run multiple programs in a bat file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

### Objective

Distribute a software with GDAL as a dependency.

To do that I have downloaded gdal binaries from [GIS Internals](https://www.gisinternals.com/release.php). The downloaded data has a `.bat` file to set environment variables. It uses `set` command to set the environment variables.

As per my limited knowledge in windows bash scripting, I understand that the environment variables set by `set` are limited to current command prompt itself and are reset when a new command prompt is launched.

Also, is it true that a calling a batch file from a batch file launches new command prompt which when closes doesn't affect the next command called in the parent script.

There is another issue here - will the environment variables affect the process created (such as calling gdal_translate) by a Java program? If it doesn't, then there is no point in setting local environment variable.

---

### Final Requirement:

How to use the environment variables set in another batch file (called from a batch file) in the next line of the parent batch file, without using `setx`?

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `CALL` command to run the batch file as specified in the accepted answer on the question you linked to, then the environment variables will pass up to the parent batch file.

There are three times where this is *not* true:

- When using [`SETX`](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) neither the parent nor child batch file will get the environment variables.
- When using [`SETLOCAL`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) and [`ENDLOCAL`](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) inside the child batch file the parent batch file will not get the environment variables.
- When running the child batch file using `start` or `cmd.exe /c`.

So long as you run your Java application in the same environment (i.e. the same batch file), it will pick up the same environment variables. You can verify this with an application like [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Running `set _kjhgkjshdgkjhdfg=TEST` before running a `.jar` file resulted in the screenshot below using any of:

- `javaw -jar jarfile.jar`
- `cmd /c javaw -jar jarfile.jar`
- `start cmd /c javaw -jar jarfile.jar`

[image: Process Explorer]

Comment: What about a Java program which calls a program using processbuilder? Can that program access the variables set using `SET`?

Comment: Is there a way to verify the environment?

Comment: Also, I didn't use the call command. There were some problems with it. I used `start \f CMD \c javaw -jar jarfile.jar` and I remember it not picking up the values. I'll try to put the relevant screenshots if you want by recreating the scenario tomorrow. I don't have access to any system now.

Comment: I'd have to verify before accepting your answer here. But thanks.

Comment: Can you please post that program as a post script to your answer.

Comment: What about that `set` which ran in another bat file which was invoked using `start CMD \c abc.bat`

Comment: You seem to have changed the answer. Which helps me understand but doesn't solve the problem. I'll try something else. Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? If you're having issues getting `CALL` to work, then you need to add that to your question.

Comment: I have Java code calling `gdal_translate`. To make the code portable and avoid installation in user system, I downloaded gdal binaries, which contained a script to set environment variables. So, I created a bat file which first called that script and launched my program. When that program ran `gdal_translate`, it failed that some DLL file is missing. That bat file to initialise has `set`, I changed it to `setx`, ran that script once and launched the Java program which worked fine. But, I don't want to ask users to permanently set their environmental variables, as it might get messy.

Comment: it might get messy when they change directories and run that script again. And I heard that environmental variables have size limit and they get truncated.

Comment: What I'm thinking now is run the Java program from that script itself so that those variables will be picked up as you mentioned in you other answer.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you're asking in this question is only tangentially related to the actual problem. I suggest creating a new question and describing the actual problem, which is a missing DLL file and/or an issue with an existing batch file. In the new question post the batch file as part of the question so people have context for answering.

Comment: Missing DLL was solved when I ran the script using `setx` and then separately running the program. But, as you said, I shall write a new question.

Comment: I agree, it is an XY problem.

Comment: What is the software you used to check the variables picked up by the java program, in the screenshot?

Comment: There is a problem with using `Call` to start a bat file. The bat file runs and exits the operation, the steps specified after `Call` in the parent bat file are not executed.

Comment: The program is Process Explorer, as linked in the answer. Are you using `EXIT` in the child batch file? Is there an error? `CALL` is specifically used to allow the execution to continue.