# AZ Login in Bat file

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I've written a bat file that needs to do daily maintenance on the storage accounts. The issue is
I'm using *az login* logging in with a service principal, and then after that I have the commands for the az storage command. Problem is that the login runs but then does not run the next command. I have to manually copy this to command line and then it runs. I want to automate this task, so currently it's not ideal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try add in some debug steps like `az account show` after the login to see if the CLI has a context set?

Comment: Hi 

I put it in the bat file after login, it stopped like it normally does after the login. 
If I paste the az account show into command line it returns account information

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, had to add `call` before any az command

For example, this script will not execute commands after `az login`

```
@echo off
az login
az network nsg rule update 1...
az network nsg rule update 2...
```

This script will execute the az commands in order, waiting for one to complete before running the next.

```
@echo off
call az login
call az network nsg rule update 1...
call az network nsg rule update 2...
```

Comment: Anyone happen to know why CALL is needed to make it not exit the entire script when `az` exits?

Comment: @StevenLiekens The `az` command actually calls `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd` (you can find this by executing `where az` in a Windows CMD window). When one batch file starts another one without the `call` command, the first one automatically quits. In contrast, the `call` command causes the first batch file to only pause while the second one runs. It's a backwards compatibilty issue that is explained in the History section of [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1104093/307747).