# getting right start directory with processing

Tags: batch-file, processing

I'm opening bat file using processing executable file. all it does is
`start Exe2.exe` and then looks for files until they are created. that bat is located in a specific folder which also has Exe2.exe. When I open it by double clicking, it works as intended but whenever I use

```
try {
      p1 = r.exec("cmd /c start " + Path + "/open.bat");
    }
      catch(Exception c) {
    }
```

it opens bat file and I get error "Windows cannot find Exe2.exe" and in console this is what it runs
[C:\Users\syste\Downloads\processing-3.5.4> start Exe2.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTKa1.png)

the starting path is different from where open.bat file is. It's start from where processing is saved. If there's a way to have it start from correct folder or somehow pass the path with processing. I don't want to hardcode path into it manually since i want it to run on different computers

open.bat content:

```
start Exe2.exe

cls

@ECHO OFF

SET LookForFile="answer.txt"

:CheckForFile
IF EXIST %LookForFile% GOTO FoundIt

GOTO CheckForFile


:FoundIt
echo the number is:
more answer.txt

del "answer.txt"

GOTO CheckForFile
```

simple sketch to reproduce:

```
String Path;
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p1;

void setup(){
   Path = sketchPath()+"/lib";
   try {
    p1 = r.exec("cmd /c start " + Path + "/open.bat");
  }
  catch(Exception c) {
  }

}
```

There's a folder called "lib" inside sketches folder which has open.bat and Exe2.exe files

Comment: Would it be possible to post a minimal sketch (and ideally) the file structure you plan to use ? It's a bit tricky to reproduce otherwise and it may lead to many wrong assumptions in understanding/solving the problem. (You can use the `tree` command (remember the `/F` flag prints files and folder and `/A` uses ASCII character (in case formatting looks strange on stackverflow)). Assuming you eventually want to export the sketch as a .exe, you should be able to place the .bat and exe2.exe files in the data folder and use  `dataPath`.

Comment: Bare in mind, once you launch open.bat, the context what the current directory may be lost and pointing to exe2.exe may not work. (`%cd%` and `pushd`/ `popd` should help with that). You should also post the contents of open.bat.

Comment: updated it with open.bat content and simple sketch to reproduce it

Comment: Thank you for the update. If I got this right, let's say you have a sketch named ExeLauncherSketch, it would contain a lib folder which in turn contains open.bat and exe2.exe ? Did I get this right ?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Try changing `start Exe2.exe` to `start "%~dp0Exe2.exe"`, which should prefix the `.exe` name with the **d**rive and **p**ath of the batch file.

Comment: It did execute the Exe2.exe but in a weird way. Exe2.exe shouldve created a text file but instead it launched a python console.

Comment: I removed quotation marks from "%~dp0Exe2.exe" and it works fine now. thanks

Comment: A bit off-topic, but would exe2.exe do something that could be programmed in Processing directly ? (I'm curious because the contents of open.bat can be programmed in Processing: even though the syntax might be slightly lengthier, it would simplify the launch processes(just one exe, no crazy path hoops to jump through, launching 2 more commands),etc.).

Comment: I'm using neural network library written in python.

Comment: The reverse applies: you can use Python's [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module to launch open.bat (via `subprocess.call` / `subprocess.check_output` / etc.). I suspect the Processing sketch needs to do something more complex too, right ? (If so, remember that if it's simply drawing shapes on basic interation there are other python packages that can help (e.g. pyprocessing (a bit outdated), pygame, kivy, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, using a file structure like this:

```
C:.
│   ExeLauncherSketch.pde
│
└───lib
        exe2.cmd
        open.bat
```

Where `exe2.cmd` is a placeholder for exe2.exe:

```
@echo "exe2 placeholder script"
timeout 10
```

You could do something like:

```
void setup() {
  String path = sketchPath("lib");
  
  try {
    exec(path + "/open.bat", path);
  }catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  exit();
}
```

This is a workaround where you pass the path to the sketch from the processing sketch to open.bat, you can read/use as the 1st command line argument (`%1`)

which would make open.bat:

```
@ECHO "path received "
start %1/Exe2.cmd

cls

@ECHO OFF

SET LookForFile="%1/answer.txt"

:CheckForFile
IF EXIST %LookForFile% GOTO FoundIt

GOTO CheckForFile


:FoundIt
echo the number is:
more answer.txt

del "%1/answer.txt"

GOTO CheckForFile
```

**Update** Magoo's answer is what I was looking for (but couldn't remember): a way to get the path where the file is located.

This would simplify the sketch to:

```java
void setup() {
  try {
    exec(sketchPath("lib/open.bat"));
  }catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  exit();
}
```

and swapping `%1` with `%~dp0`:

```
@ECHO "path received "
start %~dp0Exe2.cmd

cls

@ECHO OFF

SET LookForFile="%~dp0answer.txt"

:CheckForFile
IF EXIST %LookForFile% GOTO FoundIt

GOTO CheckForFile


:FoundIt
echo the number is:
more answer.txt

del "%~dp0/answer.txt"

GOTO CheckForFile
```

(Remember there's a difference between `start` and `call` (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)))

**Update**
The `lib` folder is a special folder. When you export an application, the Processing .jar files usually live there which means your .bat/.exe files from the original sketch might not make it to the exported application.windows64 folder. You will need to manually copy the .bat/.exe files to the lib folder after the export process completes. May advice is to rename the `lib` folder to `data` in the sketch (and update the path to open.bat in the sketch (e.g. `exec(sketchPath("data/open.bat"));` (or maybe even `exec(dataPath("open.bat"));`  ): this way you'd have a cleaner structure with .bat/.exe files on a folder and .jar files in another)