# batch file stop running after i run another file

Tags: batch-file

So I have

```
:function (
    file.bat
    echo test
    goto:function
)
```

When I call the function, file.bat get executed but nothing more happen, even when file.bat arrive to the end.

I tried to put the echo before the execution of file.bat and the text is printed, I figured out that the script stop running after the execution of a file. Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: The `(` is not relevant - it's ignored as a label is terminated at the first separator (space). You are then executing `file,bat`, which transfers execution to that batch, never to return. You need to `call file.bat` in order that execution resumes in *this* batch once the `call`ed batch ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `file.bat` with `call file.bat`.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file).