# Bat file does not wait to finish the previous script, not being executed in its entirety

Tags: windows, batch-file

Bat file does not wait to finish the previous script, not being executed in its entirety

The script I'm trying to run is:

```
@echo off
flutter create project
timeout 25 /timeout
chdir "project\lib"
md module_name && chdir module_name
md "domain/entities","domain/repositories"
md "data"
md "presentation/pages/page_name/controllers"
exit
```

And it works properly to create a flutter project, however everything else doesn't run. If I remove the creation of a flutter project from the file, doing only as below, it also runs successfully:

```
@echo off
md module_name && chdir module_name
md "domain/entities","domain/repositories"
md "data"
md "presentation/pages/page_name/controllers"
exit
```

Successfully creating the following directory structure:

```
module_name
     |
     |__domain
     |    |
     |    |__entities
     |    |__repositories
     |
     |__presentation
     |    |
     |    |__pages
     |        |
     |        |__page_name
     |            |__controllers
     |
     |__data
```

How can I get everything inside the file to run?

Comment: `CALL flutter ....` Assuming `flutter` is a batch file, without the `call`, execution is transferred to `flutter`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run multiple .BAT files within a .BAT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 0):

Using `call` before `flutter create` worked for me. I also removed the `timeout` line.

Thanks to everyone who responded. The file looked finally like this:

```
@echo off
call flutter create project
chdir "project\lib"
md module_name && chdir module_name
md "domain/entities","domain/repositories"
md "data"
md "presentation/pages/page_name/controllers"
```