# Run make.bat in powershell for sphinx

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, python-sphinx

I can execute these commands in Powershell on Windows 10

```
.\make.bat clean
rm .\source\bundle\*.*
cd ..
sphinx-apidoc -o docs/source/bundle .\bundle\ -M
cd  docs
.\make.bat html
```

and they work in a python with environment activated in Powershell. However once added all to a batch file to automate this nothing but the removal part works.

I tried to add everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file) before sphinx and the make.bat. But nothing happens.

Any Idea how to properly call sphinx and make.bat in a Windows Powershell batch/ps file ?

Comment: As shown in the linked post, you need `call` in order to call another batch file from a batch file _and have execution continue_ in the calling file. Apart from that, you'll need to replace `rm` with `del`.

Comment: That said, if you simply place the code in your question in a `.ps1` file - a _PowerShell_ script -  instead, and call it from a PowerShell session, it should work.

Comment: tried also in CMD with call in the batch. Still same result. Don't care if CMD or Powershell. Just need to automate on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command [rm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rm) is a Unix/Linux/Mac **shell** interpreter command of `ash`, `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `sh`, `zsh`, ... The **PowerShell** cmdlet for file removal is [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) and the **Windows Command Processor** command for file deletion is [del](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/del).

`make.bat` is a batch file processed by the **Windows Command Processor** `cmd.exe`. It makes sense for that reason to put all commands for the task into a batch file and run this batch file either from within a command prompt window or a PowerShell console.

The batch file should contain the following command lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0" || exit /B 1
call make.bat clean
del /A /F /Q source\bundle\*
cd ..
sphinx-apidoc -o docs\source\bundle .\bundle\ -M
cd docs
call make.bat html
popd
endlocal
```

All commands in this batch file with exception of `sphinx-apidoc` are internal [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) of `cmd.exe`.

The first two command lines define completely the required execution environment which is:

1. Command echo mode turned off.
2. Command extensions enabled.
3. Delayed variable expansion disabled.

The execution of the batch file does not depend on command processor configuration outside of the batch file because of these two command lines. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

The third command line pushes the current working directory on stack of `cmd.exe` which can be any directory and makes the directory containing the currently executed batch file the current working directory. This should never fail as the batch file is processed currently by `cmd.exe` but there is nevertheless the conditional command operator `||` used to execute the command `exit` with option `/B` and exit code `1` for exiting the batch file processing if command `pushd` failed making the batch file directory the current working directory. See [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for a more detailed explanation of the conditional command operator `||`.

Next is **called** from within this batch file the batch file `make.bat` with the argument `clean`. It is necessary to use the command `call` as otherwise without `call` the batch file processing would continue on `make.bat` without returning back to this batch file on reaching the end of the processing of the batch file `make.bat`. The missing usage of command `call` is the reason why the batch file posted in the question just makes the clean operation on execution and nothing else.

The command `del` is used next to delete all files in subdirectory `source\bundle` including hidden files because of option `/A` (all attributes instead of implicit default `/A-H` excluding hidden files) and read-only files because of option `/F` (force deletion of read-only files) quietly because of option `/Q`.

Then the current working directory is changed to the parent directory of the batch file directory.

There is executed `sphinx-apidoc` before the current working directory is changed (back) to the subdirectory `docs` where the batch file `make.bat` is called a second time but this time with argument `html`.

Finally the initial current working directory is restored with command `popd` of which absolute path is popped from stack of `cmd.exe` and the initial execution environment is restored with command `endlocal`.

The [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) of the batch file containing only [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) characters must be with one byte per character using the [OEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_equipment_manufacturer) [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) as displayed on opening a command prompt window and running either `chcp` or `mode con`. There should be used `ANSI` if the used text editor does not support the selection of the `OEM` code page.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window (start `cmd.exe`), execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains also `%~dp0` ... drive and full path of argument 0 which is the full batch file directory path always ending with a backslash.
- `cd /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `setlocal /?`