# Running all commands inside a .bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file

Can someone tell me why after executing a .bat script only the first mvn deploy command is executed and then execution close. Why all command are not executed?

```
set GROUP_BASE=com.oracle.jdeveloper.jars
set VERSION=10.1.3.3.0.4157
set JDEV_HOME=C:/Oracle/jdevstudio10133
set REPO_URL=http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty
set REPOSITORY_ID=thirdparty
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%GROUP_BASE%.BC4J_lib -DartifactId=bc4jct -Dversion=%VERSION% -Dfile=%JDEV_HOME%/BC4J/lib/bc4jct.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=%REPOSITORY_ID% -Durl=%REPO_URL%
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%GROUP_BASE%.BC4J_lib -DartifactId=adfm -Dversion=%VERSION% -Dfile=%JDEV_HOME%/BC4J/lib/adfm.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=%REPOSITORY_ID% -Durl=%REPO_URL%
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%GROUP_BASE%.BC4J_jlib -DartifactId=bc4jui -Dversion=%VERSION% -Dfile=%JDEV_HOME%/BC4J/jlib/bc4jui.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=%REPOSITORY_ID% -Durl=%REPO_URL%
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%GROUP_BASE%.jlib -DartifactId=osdt_core -Dversion=%VERSION% -Dfile=%JDEV_HOME%/jlib/osdt_core.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=%REPOSITORY_ID% -Durl=%REPO_URL%
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%GROUP_BASE%.ord_jlib -DartifactId=ordim -Dversion=%VERSION% -Dfile=%JDEV_HOME%/ord/jlib/ordim.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=%REPOSITORY_ID% -Durl=%REPO_URL%
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%GROUP_BASE%.xdoclet-1_2_1 -DartifactId=xdoclet-ibm-module-1.2.1 -Dversion=%VERSION% -Dfile=%JDEV_HOME%/xdoclet-1.2.1/xdoclet-ibm-module-1.2.1.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=%REPOSITORY_ID% -Durl=%REPO_URL%
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%GROUP_BASE%.jlib -DartifactId=jssl-1_1 -Dversion=%VERSION% -Dfile=%JDEV_HOME%/jlib/jssl-1_1.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=%REPOSITORY_ID% -Durl=%REPO_URL%
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%GROUP_BASE%.jlib -DartifactId=javax-ssl-1_1 -Dversion=%VERSION% -Dfile=%JDEV_HOME%/jlib/javax-ssl-1_1.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=%REPOSITORY_ID% -Durl=%REPO_URL%
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing multiple commands from a Windows cmd script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197976/executing-multiple-commands-from-a-windows-cmd-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with using the [CALL](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php) command.

```
...
call mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%GROUP_BASE%.BC4J_lib -DartifactId=bc4jct -Dversion=%VERSION% -Dfile=%JDEV_HOME%/BC4J/lib/bc4jct.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=%REPOSITORY_ID% -Durl=%REPO_URL%
call mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%GROUP_BASE%.BC4J_lib -DartifactId=adfm -Dversion=%VERSION% -Dfile=%JDEV_HOME%/BC4J/lib/adfm.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=%REPOSITORY_ID% -Durl=%REPO_URL%
...
```

If you invoke a command without using CALL, control passes over to the new program and does not return (in your example this is what happens after the first `mvn ...`). CALL returns control to the caller and execution continues with the next instruction.

Comment: @Bobby: "start" opens up a new CMD window and I don't think you want a window for each command (especially if you have lots of them :D). I also think that "start" does not wait for the process to terminate, but I might be wrong about that.

Comment: @dpb: I've never noticed that that one would open a new cmd. :/ Also, I thought that was asked, that it runs 'asynchron'...

Comment: I believe `CALL` is only relevant when calling another batch file.

Comment: @aphoria CALL is valid for any executable (START calls ShellExecute and can open any registered type or url protocol, but the command will run in a new window etc)

Comment: @aphoria: Some tools actully use a batch file which can lead to unexpected things. `ant` is such a tool too.

Comment: @Anders You are correct. I guess I just haven't seen a reason to use `CALL` with an executable. Using `CALL` to call another batch file returns control to the original batch file when the secondary batch file is complete. What does using `CALL` with a .EXE do for you? I did some limited testing, but could not tell a difference.

Comment: @Johannes I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for each line you are running mvn:

```
START /WAIT "" mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=%GROUP_BASE%.BC4J_lib -DartifactId=bc4jct -Dversion=%VERSION% -Dfile=%JDEV_HOME%/BC4J/lib/bc4jct.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=%REPOSITORY_ID% -Durl=%REPO_URL%
```

Comment: Robs you of all output in a single window, though. You may want to add `/B` too.