# How to call two batches from a third one?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7-x64

When my Windows Batch file (.bat) calls other two BAT files it exits after the first one.

How to make it run both of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing multiple commands from a Windows cmd script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197976/executing-multiple-commands-from-a-windows-cmd-script)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `call`

e.g. in the calling batch file:

```
call batch1.bat
call batch2.bat
```

(also, some more background [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php).)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using `call` as mikej notes, if you need to return an error code from one of the batch files then use

```
exit /b 0
```

I think if the last command invoked in a batch file returns a non-zero errorlevel then this is returned as the errorlevel of the batch file itself by default.